# Mods apparently could not see my deleted comment when reviewing my flag-- why?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism, deleted-comments, moderator-tools

I recently flagged an answer in which the answerer took the contents of my comment- which provided additional context to their answer- and pasted it verbatim at the top of their answer.  My comment on the post was then subsequently removed without any action on my part; my assumption is that it was flagged by the answerer as "no longer needed" as they had pasted its contents into their answer.  I considered this to be plagiarism, and as such I flagged the answer, including all of this information in the flag.

My flag was recently declined with the statement **"There are no deleted comments from you on this question"**.  However, I 100% **did** have a comment on this post that was subsequently removed.  I recall writing the content as it is pasted in the answer, and it matches my other comments and formatting.  I can see the edit in which it was added. Furthermore, in my flag, I noted that a remaining comment on the post was actually a *reply* to my original comment (this reply was also subsequently removed).

**My question is: How is it possible that a mod was unable to see my deleted comments on the post that I flagged?**  I was under the impression that mods were able to see deleted comments, but clearly something has gone wrong here.  Does this represent some bug in the SO software or data retention processes?  Or simple human error?

I have resigned myself to the fact that there will probably be no remediation for this small act of (what I believe is) plagiarism, but I am interested as to the mechanics of how this issue of the invisible/missing comment came to be, and if it requires some action to to ensure deleted comments are available for mod audits in future.

To answer a few questions before they might be asked:

- **Why haven't I included a link to the post in question?**

  I wanted to avoid publicly drawing negative attention to this individual or any sort of "[brigading](https://institute.global/policy/social-media-futures-what-brigading#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CBrigading%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20term%20that,dedicated%20to%20a%20particular%20topic)".
- **Why didn't I simply post a new comment requesting the answerer provide proper credit for my content?**

  Similar to the above-- I didn't want to publicly accuse this person of plagiarism.  I felt leaving it to the mods would be the most discreet and official approach.
- **Why didn't I revert their edit to remove my content from their answer?**

  Getting into a battle of two users editing a post back and forth didn't seem like a correct nor fruitful avenue of remediation.
- **Why did I even care about this?  It was just a comment, after all.**

  I care for two reasons:

  - First, while I know there has perhaps been some fumfering in Meta regarding whether or not comments deserve citation, I felt that copying my comment *verbatim* potentially crossed a clear line into plagiarism, which is not permitted on the site.
  - Second, at the end of the day we are all unpaid volunteers on this site; the credit we get by having our name next to the content we authored is one of the few forms of "compensation" we receive.  Seeing words that I wrote attributed to somebody else is, ultimately, something that bothers me a little.  Perhaps that is petty, but I'd be lying if I said otherwise.

Comment: You say you flagged an *answer* but cite a statement about "comments from you on this *question*". Did you flag the answer or the question? Did you comment on the answer or the question?

Comment: Are you talking about your comment on that answer? You have no comments on the question.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the comment you posted on the answer, which the author then merged into their answer and replied with "@AlexanderNied added to solution, thanks!". If this is what you are talking about, then there's no action to be taken by mods. It's all as it should be, you posted a clarification and the author accepted it by putting it in the post. That's the whole point of providing comments on answers, isn't it?

Comment: I made the flag on the **answer**-- I can verify this by looking at the flag and clicking the link, which loads the answer.  I am referring to comments I made on this answer, which I refer to in the text of the flag.  It is a good point raised by several in the comments here that the reviewer comment refers to the **question**, so perhaps there was some confusion in the review process and the reviewer was looking at the question, not the answer I flagged.

Comment: @Dharman - I am referring to the comment made on the answer, yes.  I never saw their reply-- it must have been removed before I was able to read it. I would generally expect verbatim copy to include some citation, but that is ultimately immaterial to this question-- from your statement it appears my deleted comment _is_ visible, and the comment _"There are no deleted comments from you on this question"_ was just a result of some confusion/misunderstanding in the flag review.  Thank you for providing the missing context for me on this issue!

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be just a misunderstanding. If you provided the comment on the answer then it makes sense that it was copied into the answer it was posted on. If you would have made a comment on the question and then the answerer took it without your permission or attribution, it would be a little different.

Comment: This meta question has a point though: apparently, the "Load [X] deleted comments" link that is shown by default on the main site is not shown if seen from the mod queue. They have to manually check the Mod menu to see if there are deleted comments or not on the flagged post.

Comment: @Makyen huh, the deleted comments are not shown by default for the "More than 20 comments posted in the past 3 days" flag after I moved them to the chat.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. Yeah, you're right; my bad. I failed to check to see if the deleted comments were added by a userscript. I'm using Sam's [Comment Flags Helper](//github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/CommentFlagsHelper.user.js), which auto-adds deleted comments to that view. I'm sorry about claiming it was the default. Given how many userscripts I use, I know better to claim something like that is default without double-checking to see if it's what really happens in the stock display. In this case, I guess I'm just too used to that functionality being what always happens for me.

Comment: @Dharman *"If you would have made a comment on the question and then the answerer took it without your permission or attribution, it would be a little different."* . How is it different? The final result is the same, the answerer has text in their post which isn't correctly attributed. And why is it important if the answerer thanked OP in a comment or not?

Comment: Since when is it OK or good etiquette to not provide attribution to the author of a comment when *copy-pasting it verbatim* into your post? Attribution such as: `additionally, as stated by [@x](link) through a comment: <copied comment>` seems like the bare minimum. It'd be another story if the comment was taken as suggestion and elaborated on, but this is not the case.

Comment: @Tom: Say a commenter to the question provides half-way answers via comments -- often that does happen and it's due to the need to clarify the question-- should the commenter be given the chance to use their own comments to formulate an answer? Doesn't another user copy-pasting those comments without asking take that opportunity away?

Comment: I think it's more important to have better answers than imaginary points and pseudonymous attribution, so this looks like a net win.

Comment: @Cactus So the answer would be worse if it has the proper attribution?

Comment: @Cactus I think it's more important to show experts that their contributions are honored than to be lazy about even the most simplest attributions, so this looks like a net loss in the long run.

Comment: @Cactus this metric is very wrong. You are one step too close to justifying plagiarizing content for the sake of having a "better answer". Of course an answer including a verbatim copy of somebody's else content may look "better" and provide more information, but that doesn't mean that it is OK (it's not). OTOH stating the author of a quote when copying it verbatim adds little-to-no noise and makes everybody happy.

Answer (score 32):

Thanks to [mod Dharman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) for [providing the missing context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/mods-apparently-could-not-see-my-deleted-comment-when-reviewing-my-flag-why?noredirect=1#comment918002_419163):

> *I assume you are talking about the comment you posted on the answer, which the author then merged into their answer and replied with "@AlexanderNied added to solution, thanks!". If this is what you are talking about, then there's no action to be taken by mods. It's all as it should be, you posted a clarification and the author accepted it by putting it in the post.*

So it appears a few things happened here:

1. There was some confusion in the flag review process-- it appears perhaps the reviewer was looking for my comment on the *question*, whereas I was actually referring to a comment on the *answer*.  I'm not casting blame here-- perhaps my explanation in the flag was not sufficiently clear.  **Critically, Dharman has verified that my deleted comments *are* visible to Mods as expected.**
2. Apparently the answerer *did* post in a reply comment that they had pasted my context-providing comment into their answer, and thanked me for providing the content; **however, because the answerer's comment was deleted shortly thereafter, I never saw the  reply**.

While generally I would still expect that citation be provided in the answer when pasting content verbatim, obviously the fact that the answerer publicly stated they had used it and thanking me casts the entire interaction in a very different light.  **Ultimately, however, this Meta post was about why the deleted comment would be missing for mods, which Dharman has answered.**

Comment: "_however, because the answerer's comment was deleted shortly thereafter, I never saw the reply_" <- this is why aggressively deleting thank-you-looking comments is harmful. Sure, we don't want comments like that to stick around forever. But perhaps wait until the other user has a chance to read it?

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні nah man, it adds so much noise! Ever tried to read a post with a small comment underneath that somehow includes the words "thank you"? It's so noisy that I literally cannot comprehend a single word of what I am reading, even if the comment is *under* the post. Sometimes they are so noisy that I literally need ear protection. **/s**

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thank you ;)